# How to get staked amount of an account in Solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

I am building a stake pool for my spl-token on Solana. On my website I can get staked amount of an address by Anchor to call rpc API via connected program.

Is there any way to get staked amount of a wallet address from my server?

Comment: You'll need to add some more context here, since "staked amount" appears to be a property of your Anchor program.  Most likely, you need to keep user information about how much they have staked, or you need to issue a separate stake pool token to users who have staked.

Answer (score 0):

the following API call should work:

```
H = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
B = f''' {{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getVoteAccounts"
}}'''
r = requests.post(RPC_URL, headers=H, data=B).json()['result']
print(r)
```